# PHP suppress errors when checking existence + value of boolean?

Tags: php, coding-style, refactoring

I have a PHP script that uses an array of options: $opts[]

$opts can contain 0 or more key value pairs.  All values are boolean.

When checking for existence of a key, and then that the value is true, I have been doing the following:

```
if(isset($opts['small']) && $opts['small']) $classes .= 'smallBtn';
```

This works, but I feel it is a bit long winded.

After having a think about it, I have come up with the following alternative:

```
if(@$opts['small']) $classes .= "smallBtn";
```

This is much smaller, but relies on the @ error suppression.

My question is, which is the better way to do this?

First is long winded, but explicit in what it is doing.

Second is shorter, but may be seen as bad coding practice?

UPDATE:

The 3rd option, and in my opinion the best, is using [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if(!empty($opts['small'])) $classes .= 'smallBtn';
```

From the manual:

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @ to suppress errors is usually a bad thing to do since it makes debugging really difficult. For example, say you make a typo in variable name (note the double dollar sign):

```
if(@$$opts['small']) $classes .= "smallBtn";
```

This will be constantly false without throwing any errors.

If you want to shorten your code, maybe just use a function, something like:

```
function optionIsTrue($opts, $key) {
    return isset($opts[$key]) && $opts[$key] === true;
}

if (optionIsTrue($opts, "small")) {
    $classes .= 'smallBtn';
}
```

Comment: I just updated the question to include the 3rd option of using empty() - what do you think?

Comment: any thoughts on the use of empty?

Comment: @psynnott empty seems to be a valid option for this use case but still as manual states: "A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or..." - it is still easy to swallow typos in variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would prefer the first approach with respect to *Clean Code guidelines* and *Code Readability*.

I wouldn't suppress any errors whereever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to do the long-winded check so that the error never occurs. Suppressing the error fixes the symptom but does not fix the error. The following excerpt from your question is the correct answer:

```
if(isset($opts['small']) && $opts['small']) $classes .= 'smallBtn';
```

You're right-on with wanting to make code shorter and easier to read.  But I've seen a lot of PHP code done by other experts and the only '@' error suppression I have ever seen in production code is one I put there myself as a quick fix. After being chastised by colleagues, I promptly put in the proper long-winded check so the error never occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a comment but you couldn't see the diference, here it goes:
Well, according to [PEAR Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.control.php) you should simply, first one is the better aproach but for the best pratice, and for best understand after looking at it, just try to read this one:

```
if(isset($opts['small']) 
   && $opts['small'] 
) {
     $classes .= 'smallBtn'; 
}
```

And as much as i know, you never should suppress errors